# SIGSEGV When accessing array element using assembly

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

### Background:

I am new to assembly. When I was learning programming, I made a program that implements multiplication tables up to 1000 * 1000. The tables are formatted so that each answer is on the line `factor1 << 10 | factor2` (I know, I know, it's isn't pretty). These tables are then loaded into an array: `int* tables`. Empty lines are filled with 0. [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97304035/tables.multiplicationTables) is a link to the file for the tables (7.3 MB). I know using assembly won't speed up this by much, but I just wanted to do it for fun (and a bit of practice).

### Question:

I'm trying to convert this code into inline assembly (`tables` is a global):

```
int answer;
// ...
answer = tables [factor1 << 10 | factor2];
```

This is what I came up with:

```
asm volatile ( "shll $10, %1;"
           "orl %1, %2;"
           "movl _tables(,%2,4), %0;" : "=r" (answer) : "r" (factor1), "r" (factor2) );
```

My C++ code works fine, but my assembly fails. **What is wrong with my assembly (especially the `movl _tables(,%2,4), %0;` part), compared to my C++**

### What I have done to solve it:

I used some random numbers: 89 796 as `factor1` and `factor2`. I *know* that there is an element at `89 << 10 | 786` (which is `91922`) – verified this with C++. When I run it with `gdb`, I get a SIGSEGV:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

at this line:

```
"movl _tables(,%2,4), %0;" : "=r" (answer) : "r" (factor1), "r" (factor2) );
```

I added two methods around my `asm`, which is how I know where the `asm` block is in the disassembly.

#### Disassembly of my `asm` block:

The disassembly from `objdump -M att -d` looks fine (although I'm not sure, I'm new to assembly, as I said):

```
402096: 8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
402099: 8b 55 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
40209c: c1 e0 0a                shl    $0xa,%eax
40209f: 09 c2                   or     %eax,%edx
4020a1: 8b 04 95 18 e0 47 00    mov    0x47e018(,%edx,4),%eax
4020a8: 89 45 ec                mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
```

The disassembly from `objdump -M intel -d`:

```
402096: 8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
402099: 8b 55 0c                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
40209c: c1 e0 0a                shl    eax,0xa
40209f: 09 c2                   or     edx,eax
4020a1: 8b 04 95 18 e0 47 00    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [edx*4+0x47e018]
4020a8: 89 45 ec                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14],eax
```

From what I understand, it's moving the first parameter of my `void calc ( int factor1, int factor2 )` function into `eax`. Then it's moving the second parameter into `edx`. Then it shifts `eax` to the left by 10 and `or`s it with `edx`. A 32-bit integer is 4 bytes, so [`[edx*4+base_address]`](http://cs.smith.edu/%7Ethiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH05/CH05-2.html#HEADING2-4). Move result to `eax` and then put `eax` into `int answer` (which, I'm guessing is on `-0x14` of the stack). **I don't really see much of a problem.**

#### Disassembly of the compiler's `.exe`:

When I replace the `asm` block with plain C++ (`answer = tables [factor1 << 10 | factor2];`) and disassemble it this is what I get in Intel syntax:

```
402096: a1 18 e0 47 00          mov    eax,ds:0x47e018
40209b: 8b 55 08                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
40209e: c1 e2 0a                shl    edx,0xa
4020a1: 0b 55 0c                or     edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
4020a4: c1 e2 02                shl    edx,0x2
4020a7: 01 d0                   add    eax,edx
4020a9: 8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
4020ab: 89 45 ec                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14],eax
```

AT&T syntax:

```
402096: a1 18 e0 47 00          mov    0x47e018,%eax
40209b: 8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
40209e: c1 e2 0a                shl    $0xa,%edx
4020a1: 0b 55 0c                or     0xc(%ebp),%edx
4020a4: c1 e2 02                shl    $0x2,%edx
4020a7: 01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
4020a9: 8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
4020ab: 89 45 ec                mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
```

I am not really familiar with the Intel syntax, so I am just going to try and understand the AT&T syntax:

It first moves the base address of the `tables` array into `%eax`. Then, is moves the first parameter into `%edx`. It shifts `%edx` to the left by 10 then `or`s it with the second parameter. Then, by shifting `%edx` to the left by two, it actually multiplies `%edx` by 4. Then, it adds that to `%eax` (the base address of the array). So, basically it just did this: `[edx*4+0x47e018]` (Intel syntax) or `0x47e018(,%edx,4)` AT&T. It moves the value of the element it got into `%eax` and puts it into `int answer`. **This method is more "expanded", but it does the same thing as my hand-written assembly! So why is mine giving a `SIGSEGV` while the compiler's working fine?**

Comment: Why are you trying to do a compilers job?

Comment: @TonyTheLion just read the question: _"I know using assembly won't speed up this by much, but I just wanted to do it for fun (and a bit of practice)."_

Comment: "someone is trying to be a compiler" sounded way funnier, @Tony.

Comment: The `volatile` part of `asm volatile` tells the compiler that it cannot move your piece of assembly at all, and it cannot move other parts of the code around your assembly either.  This prevents the compilers built-in optimizer from doing its job.  You should not specify your assembly as `volatile` unless you are sure you need to do so and you understand why.  A good example of something that needs it is `rdtsc`, because you don't want the compiler moving that code or it will time the wrong thing.

Comment: @SoapBox Thanks for pointing that out, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet (from the disassembly) that `tables` is a pointer to an array, not the array itself.

So you need:

```
 asm volatile ( "shll $10, %1;"
        movl  _tables,%%eax
       "orl %1, %2;"
       "movl (%%eax,%2,4)",
       : "=r" (answer) : "r" (factor1), "r" (factor2) : "eax" )
```

(Don't forget the extra clobber in the last line).

There are of course variations, this may be more efficient if the code is in a loop:

```
 asm volatile ( "shll $10, %1;"
       "orl %1, %2;"
       "movl (%3,%2,4)",
       : "=r" (answer) : "r" (factor1), "r" (factor2), "r"(tables) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There was a comma at the end of the `movl` that was confusing the compiler. Other than that that, it worked very well!

Answer (score 2):

This is intended to be an addition to Mats Petersson's answer - I wrote it simply because it wasn't immediately clear to me why OP's analysis of the disassembly (that his assembly and the compiler-generated one were equivalent) was incorrect.

As Mats Petersson explains, the problem is that `tables` is actually a pointer to an array, so to access an element, you have to dereference twice. Now to me, it wasn't immediately clear *where* this happens in the compiler-generated code. The culprit is this innocent-looking line:

```
a1 18 e0 47 00          mov    0x47e018,%eax
```

To the untrained eye (that includes mine), this might look like the *value* `0x47e018` is moved to `eax`, but it's actually not. The Intel-syntax representation of the same opcodes gives us a clue:

```
a1 18 e0 47 00          mov    eax,ds:0x47e018
```

Ah - `ds:` - so it's not actually a value, but an address!

For anyone who is wondering now, the following would be the opcodes and ATT syntax assembly for moving the *value* `0x47e018` to `eax`:

```
b8 18 e0 47 00          mov    $0x47e018,%eax
```